# cannot find symbol symbol: class DockerImageName

Tags: java, junit, testcontainers

I have been trying to run an sbomtest that invokes a cyclonedx-cli docker image using test containers but the

```
import org.testcontainers.images.DockerImageName; doesn't work properly
```

Here is what I want the test to do for me

The SBOMTest class defines a GenericContainer field named cyclonedxCli that is annotated with the @Rule annotation. This container is based on the cyclonedx/cyclonedx-cli Docker image, and it maps a classpath resource at /path/to/sboms to the path /app/sboms in the container.

The testSBOMValidation method is a JUnit test that starts the cyclonedxCli container, runs the cyclonedx-cli validate command in the container to validate an SBOM file, and then stops the container.

The test method uses the execInContainer method of the GenericContainer class to run the cyclonedx-cli command in the container, and it stores the command's output and exit code in the result variable.

The test method then uses the assertThat method from the AssertJ library to assert that the command's exit code is zero. This indicates that the command completed successfully.

Finally, the test method stops the cyclonedxCli container using the stop method of the GenericContainer class.

Below is my SBOMTest class and my pom.xml. Why doesn't my test pass?

```
package com.mkyong.hashing;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.images.DockerImageName;
import org.testcontainers.images.DockerImageName;


import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class SBOMTest {

    public static final DockerImageName CYCLONEDX_CLI_IMAGE = DockerImageName.parse("cyclonedx/cyclonedx-cli:v0.24.2");

    @Rule
    public GenericContainer<?> cyclonedxCli = new GenericContainer<>(CYCLONEDX_CLI_IMAGE)
            .withClasspathResourceMapping("/home/ntn/workdir", "/app/sboms", BindMode.READ_ONLY);

    @Test
    public void testSBOMValidation() throws Exception {
        // Start the container
        cyclonedxCli.start();

        // Validate the SBOM file using the cyclonedx-cli command
        String sbomFileName = "/home/ntn/workdir/julian.json";
        Container.ExecResult result = cyclonedxCli.execInContainer("cyclonedx-cli", "validate", "--input-file", sbomFileName, "--fail-on-errors");
        String stdout = result.getStdout();

        // Assert that the command returned a zero exit code
        assertThat(result.getExitCode()).isZero();

        // Stop the container
        cyclonedxCli.stop();
    }
}
```

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.hashing</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>java-project</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <!-- https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Attach the shade into the package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.mkyong.hashing.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- fat-jar -->
            <!-- https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/customizing-sect-custom-packaged.html -->
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.mkyong.hashing.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>simple-command</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I was expecting the test to pass successfully

The following are the error logs

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.mkyong.hashing:java-project >-------------------
[INFO] Building java-project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ java-project ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ java-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ java-project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ java-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ java-project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/target/test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[6,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DockerImageName
  location: package org.testcontainers.images
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[7,33] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DockerImageName
  location: package org.testcontainers.images
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[10,35] package org.assertj.core.api does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[10,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[14,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DockerImageName
  location: class com.mkyong.hashing.SBOMTest
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[14,63] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable DockerImageName
  location: class com.mkyong.hashing.SBOMTest
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[18,78] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable BindMode
  location: class com.mkyong.hashing.SBOMTest
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[27,18] package Container does not exist
[INFO] 8 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.466 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-26T06:24:21+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project java-project: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[6,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DockerImageName
[ERROR]   location: package org.testcontainers.images
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[7,33] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DockerImageName
[ERROR]   location: package org.testcontainers.images
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[10,35] package org.assertj.core.api does not exist
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[10,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[14,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DockerImageName
[ERROR]   location: class com.mkyong.hashing.SBOMTest
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[14,63] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable DockerImageName
[ERROR]   location: class com.mkyong.hashing.SBOMTest
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[18,78] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable BindMode
[ERROR]   location: class com.mkyong.hashing.SBOMTest
[ERROR] /home/ntn/outreachytest/maven-examples/java-project/src/test/java/com/mkyong/hashing/SBOMTest.java:[27,18] package Container does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Wrong package: https://javadoc.io/static/org.testcontainers/testcontainers/1.15.1/org/testcontainers/utility/DockerImageName.html

Comment: You also seem to be importing the same class twice.